# Nativescript App Not Printing to Console

Tags: android, nativescript

I am trying to debug a Nativescript app for Android and I have noticed that it no longer prints Syntax errors with their corresponding line and col. numbers, not even console.log statements. How can I enable this feature again? The command I use to launch the app is `tns run android`. I am using Nativescript version 2.5.2. The VSCode plugin doesn't work either as it ignores any breakpoint I place, and also the console doesn't show any errors. What can I do?

**Edit:**

It appears that only `console.error()` statements get printed.

Comment: try to delete your hooks folder, and run aplication again

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the project, but rather with nativescript itself, as with previous versions everything worked fine until the end of 2016, if I recall correctly.

Comment: You can try to delete the platforms, node_modules and the app in the emulator. Sometimes cleaning the project in this way resolve unexpected strange issues. Also you can try reverting to 2.5.0, that version was rock solid for me and I still use it.

Comment: I have already tried deleting all the stuff ns generates when you compile the app, I guess reverting would be the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering a lot with different kinds of constructions and by researching more into how Nativescript relates to regular browser JS, I found out that the problem lies in the use of [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which in case of errors defer the execution to the [catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) method, but unlike any other regular programming language, "unhandled" rejected results within promises won't raise any kind of exception; which means that, basically, for any promise you invoke in your code, you should have a chained catch() method call so you effectively catch any errors your promises might produce. This also applies to promises which involve navigation, where stuff gets a lot trickier: You might think the next view (say, `view.js`) will have a call stack on its own and produce an unhandled exception at code that's not even inside a promise in there, but that's not the case: An exception produced at `view.js` will get captured by the `catch()` method of the promise within which you started the navigation, and any subsequent promises must have their own catch() method calls because errors won't get bubbled up to the previous view. I can think of many other troublesome constructions but I hope the important bit stays clear: *always chain a catch call on any and all promises*.